# Sklearn make blobs without negative values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to generate five clusters using `make_blobs` function.
The problem I have is that the generated points contain negative values, but I would like not to have negative values.

this is my current code:

```
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=2647, n_features=2, centers=6, 
       cluster_std=1.5, shuffle=True, random_state=20000)
```

and this is my data plotted:

[image: plotted data]

I tried to multiply each observation by a certain value, but the problem is that then there would be a 'straight-line' of dots close the 0, and there won't be a natural decrementation of observations.

How can I achieve this? Or better, how can I shift all my observation up to, for example, 1000?

Comment: Can you add some code so it's clear what you've done so far and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily you can do this using `make_blobs` without having to shift it manually, you can use the `center_box` parameter.

```
center_box = (100, 200) # defines the box that cluster centres are allowed to be in
standard_dev = 15 # defines the standard deviation of clusters
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=200, n_features=2, center_box=center_box, cluster_std=standard_dev)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
```

[image]

However if you want to shift all your features to start at zero you can just use `X -= X.min(axis=0)` to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now the samples are too "dispersed", and not "dense" as before, is the only way to achieve the same "visual effect" to just increase the sample size?

Comment: As per [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html) you can alter the standard deviation, see my updated answer.